# Построить КДА, который по двоичному разложению числа a строит двоичное разложение числа 3а

Tags: математика, дискретная-математика

Построить кда который по двоичному разложению числа "a" строить двоичное разложение числа "3а"

Можете пожалуйста обьяснить что вообще это за автомат такой? на вход подаётся только буква "a"? или различные числа например число 10(это двойка в десятичной системе) и я должен построить число 110(это шестёрка в десятичной системе)

.Вообще возможно ли это реализовать с помощью автомата?

Comment: Конечный автомат - очень грубо говоря, процедура, которая переходит между разными состояниями в зависимости от того, что получает на вход. У вас она получает последовательность 0 и 1, представляющую число `a`, и должна выводить последовательность для числа `3a`. *"По-моему, так". (с) Пух*

Comment: да,но вообще возможно ли построить такой автомат? есть какая нибудь закономерность например если 1 то выход 01 если потом 0 то выход 00?

Comment: Долго пытался выявить закономерность по моему её тут нет а автомат посттроить невозможно?

Comment: Если вводить, начиная с меньшего разряда - то очень даже просто... Если со старшего (не вижу в условии такого требования) - то сначала развернуть, например, в стеке. Выводить тоже по одному, начиная с младшего разряда. После того, как все число введено - добавить еще 0, получить вывод и остановиться. Расписал, по-моему, всё, что можно расписать без привязки к конкретному языку :)